# Can't use DOM Node's properties as filters on XPath / CSS Selector query

Tags: javascript, dom, xpath, css-selectors

I'm trying to search DOM elements using [DOM Node's properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node), like `innerText` and `textContent`, as filters, but without success.

Take this HTML for instance:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="one">
      <div class="two">
        <div class="three">
          <div>Text Here</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I search for a node using the class attribute I can access the `innerText` property, both with XPath (evaluate) and CSS Selector (querySelectorAll) functions:

```js
document.evaluate("//div[@class = 'one']",
    document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,
    null).singleNodeValue.innerText;

document.querySelectorAll("div.one")[0].innerText;
```

However, using `innerText` property instead of `class` gives me no result:

```js
 document.evaluate("//div[@innerText = 'Text Here']",
     document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,
     null).singleNodeValue;

 document.querySelectorAll("div[innerText='Text Here']")[0];
```

I tested with the `nodeName` and `textContent` and it failed as well, so this is why I think it is related with this DOM properties which are not tag attributes.

I tried using XPath `text()` function, but using it on `<div class="one">` from the example above won't return "Text Here".

All the tests were made on Google Chrome v67, on Linux Mint.

Why does this happens? Is there any solution or workaround for what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`innerText` is not an [*attribute*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/what-is-the-difference-between-properties-and-attributes-in-html), so `@innerText` doesn't work. Also `'Text Here'` is not a child text node of `<div class="one">`, but descendant text node, so `//div[text()='Text Here' and @class='one']` will not work (however `//div[.//text()='Text Here' and @class='one']` should work)

You should try below to locate required `div` by its *text content*:

```js
document.evaluate("(//div[.='Text Here'])[1]",
     document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,
     null).singleNodeValue;
```

If there are more descendant text nodes, but you want to locate just by `"Text Here"`, you can try XPath:

```
(//div[.//div='Text Here'])[1]
```